# Create shared folder as active directory would in powershell

Tags: active-directory, permissions, network-share, file-permissions, home-directory

With Active Directory I can manually create new users. Every time I do that, I use `right click -> Copy` on that user, then I modify some things like Name, Surname and SamAccountName. This process creates a new user with common properties with the copied user and also a home folder in our NAS (with path `$NAS_path`). I created a script to automate that and it works. The fundamental part of it is

```
$templateUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $usertocopy -Properties ObjectCategory, ObjectClass, PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount
New-ADUser -Name "$($user_name) $($user_surname)" -GivenName $user_name -Surname $user_surename -Description "employee" -SamAccountName $user_domain_name -UserPrincipalName "$($user_domain_name)@myorg" -HomeDirectory "$($NAS_path)\$($user_domain_name)" -HomeDrive "W:" -Accountpassword $password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Instance $templateUser
```

For the most part I'm ok with the result. But it just creates a new user, how can I create a folder in the NAS with "similar" permissions for the new user? By "similar" I mean that the new user can do the same things with their new folder that the old user can do with their folder. Those are the permissions of the folder `\\NASPATH\test.test` of the user with SamAccountName `test.test`:

```
Get-Acl \\NASPATH\test.test | Format-List

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\NASPATH\test.test
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : MYORG\Domain Users
Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  268435456
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         MYORG\test.test Allow  268435456
         MYORG\test.test Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         CREATOR OWNER Allow  FullControl
         MYORG\ouradmin Allow  FullControl
Audit  : 
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;OICIIO;GA;;;BA)(A;;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIO;GA;;;S-1-5-21-2801405462-3170940757-3729986713-3219)(A;;FA
         ;;;S-1-5-21-2801405462-3170940757-3729986713-3219)(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIIOID;FA;;;CO)(A;O
         ICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-2801405462-3170940757-3729986713-1530)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the user with `-HomeDirectory "\\Server\Share\%username%"` the folder will be created on logon with the user as owner.

The user needs to be able to create folders on `\\Server\Share\`. You could give this permission to a group like "all_users" which every user will be put into when creating. Give *Create files / write data* and *Create folders / append data* permissions.

As far as I'm aware, most sysadmins keep it that way.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my case. I checked that when creating a new user through manually copying an older one the shared folder gets created immediately (before user logon!). Anyway I created a user using my script and it didn't create any folder, I logged in with the new user, then I logged off and checked back the shared folders: the folder for the new user wasn't created...

Comment: By "The user needs to be able to create folders on \\Server\Share\%username%", do you mean that I need to give some permission to the user before logon? So that the folder get automatically generated at logon?

Comment: yes, you could give this permission to a group like "all_users" which every user will be put into when creating. Give "Create files / write data", "Create folders / append data"

Comment: Thank you. I guess that this is a permission problem. In particular when creating the user I didn't copy the `PrimaryGroup` and `PrimaryGroupId` properties (because I got some errors), so I think that the created user belongs to no group, therefore it has no permissions. I'll try to create a user in an actual group and see if the magic happens (the folder gets automatically created)